# Can I use icons, which I am not allowed to use in commercial applications, in a free game

Tags: legal

I wonder if I can use commercially-not-allowed icons in a mobile game which will be free for download. My game will include ads. Will ads make my game a commercial product?

Comment: Definitions of "commercial  products" and "commercial activity" vary.  It is best to read any contracts/TOS and if unclear seek legal advice.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69846/what-does-non-commercial-use-mean-in-terms-of-game-assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: IANAL! (I am not a laywer!)

A very strict definition of a commercial application is "an application made with the intent to earn money". Clearly adds are inserted into game to make money, so if the license on the icons disallows commercial use you cannot use them.